# Ranking multiple columns by different orders using data table

Tags: r, data.table

Using my example below, how can I rank multiple columns using different orders, so for example rank y as descending and z as ascending?

```
require(data.table)

dt <- data.table(x = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5)),
y = abs(rnorm(10)) * 10, z = abs(rnorm(10)) * 10)

cols <- c("y", "z")

dt[, paste0("rank_", cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) frankv(x, ties.method = "min")), .SDcols = cols, by = .(x)]
```

Comment: Does this work: `dt[, rank_y := .N - rank(y) + 1][, rank_z := rank(z)][]`

Comment: @PoGibas yes it does work but I guess I was hoping for something cleaner. I currently have 6 columns to rank in my actual data.

Answer (score 1):

`data.table`'s `frank()` function has some useful features which aren't available in base R's `rank()` function (see `?frank`). E.g., we can reverse the order of the ranking by prepending the variable with a minus sign:

```
library(data.table)
# create reproducible data
set.seed(1L)
dt <- data.table(x = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5)),
                 y = abs(rnorm(10)) * 10, z = abs(rnorm(10)) * 10)
# rank y descending, z ascending
dt[, rank_y := frank(-y), x][, rank_z := frank(z), x][]
```

> ```
>     x         y          z rank_y rank_z
>  1: a  6.264538 15.1178117      3      4
>  2: a  1.836433  3.8984324      5      1
>  3: a  8.356286  6.2124058      2      2
>  4: a 15.952808 22.1469989      1      5
>  5: a  3.295078 11.2493092      4      3
>  6: b  8.204684  0.4493361      1      2
>  7: b  4.874291  0.1619026      4      1
>  8: b  7.383247  9.4383621      2      5
>  9: b  5.757814  8.2122120      3      4
> 10: b  3.053884  5.9390132      5      3
> ```

If there are many columns which are to be ranked individually, some descending, some ascending, we can do this in two steps

```
# first rank all columns in descending order
cols_desc <- c("y")
dt[, paste0("rank_", cols_desc) := lapply(.SD, frankv, ties.method = "min", order = -1L), 
   .SDcols = cols_desc, by = x][]
# then rank all columns in ascending order
cols_asc <- c("z")
dt[, paste0("rank_", cols_asc) := lapply(.SD, frankv, ties.method = "min", order = +1L), 
   .SDcols = cols_asc, by = x][]
```

> ```
>     x         y          z rank_y rank_z
>  1: a  6.264538 15.1178117      3      4
>  2: a  1.836433  3.8984324      5      1
>  3: a  8.356286  6.2124058      2      2
>  4: a 15.952808 22.1469989      1      5
>  5: a  3.295078 11.2493092      4      3
>  6: b  8.204684  0.4493361      1      2
>  7: b  4.874291  0.1619026      4      1
>  8: b  7.383247  9.4383621      2      5
>  9: b  5.757814  8.2122120      3      4
> 10: b  3.053884  5.9390132      5      3
> ```